# Without err argument I get null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning `Express` with `Mongoose` and I am rendering a page where I run a `forEach` on a list of "campgrounds" from a `MongoDB`. My understanding is that when running the .find function it is optional to pass the `err` argument and run an `if` statement. But when I remove the `err` argument and the `if` statement altogether I get a "cannot run `forEach` on `null` while when I add it back (no other changes) my code runs smoothly. Not a problem when I add it back but I'm trying to understand what's going on in the background. Thanks in advance!

App.js code

```
//Create the camgrounds route
app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res) {
    //Get Campgrounds from DB
    Campground.find({}, function(err, dbCampgrounds) {
        //check for error
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            //render the campgrounds page passing in the campground info from the db
        } else {
            res.render("campgrounds", {
                renderCampGround: dbCampgrounds
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And ejs file code

```
<div class="row">
  <% renderCampGround.forEach(function(x){ %>
    <div class="col-med-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<%= x.image %>">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 <%= x.name %>>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `callback function` so, all callbacks in the Mongoose use the pattern `callback(err, data)`. So, if an `error` occurs while executing the query the `error` parameters will contain the `error` document and `data` will be `null`. If the query runs successfully then the error parameter will be `null`. But it is important to notice that not finding a document is not an `error`.

If you do not specify `callback function` then `API` will return the variable of type `Query`. [Have a look](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js).

So, if you don't want to use `callback function` then it will look like this.

```
//Create the camgrounds route
app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res){

    var campgrounds = Campgrounds.find({});

    //execute a query at later time
    campgrounds.exec(function (err, data) {

    if (err) {
     console.log(err)
    }
     else {
        console.log(data)
     }
   }):
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You explained it better than the teacher :) makes perfect sense now!